# How to sort and filter backbone collection

Tags: sorting, backbone.js, collections, filter

relatively new to backbone. I'm trying to filter and sort a collection before passing off to the template. I can easily sort OR filter, but I can't figure out how to do both. I tried chaining them, creating a variable to hold the filter then sort on that, but can't get anything to work. Any advice?? Thanks!

```
# Can filter like this:
monday =  @collection.where({ target: '#day-mon' })

# Can sort like this:
mondaySorted =  @collection.sortBy (t) -> t.get('order')

# Doesn't work:
mondayFilteredSorted = @collection.where({ target: '#day-mon' }).sortBy (t) -> t.get('order')

# Doesn't work:
mondaySorted = monday.sortBy (t) -> t.get('order')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that [`where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) and [`sortBy`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) return arrays — not collections — and arrays don't have `where` or `sortBy` methods. As soon as you `where` or `sortBy`, you lose access to the Backbone collection and Underscore utilities.

You can of course use Underscore directly on the array that `where` gives you:

```
_(@collection.where(target: '#day-mon')).sortBy (t) -> t.get('order')
```

or you could use `chain` and `filter`:

```
@collection.chain().filter((m) -> m.get('target') == '#day-mon').sortBy((m) -> m.get('order')).value()
```

`where` is a Backbone collection method so you have to drop down to Underscore's `filter` if you want to `chain`.

You could also use the standard [`Array::sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
by_order = (a, b) ->
    [ a, b ] = [ a.get('order'), b.get('order') ]
    return  1 if(a > b)
    return -1 if(a < b)
    return  0
@collection.where(target: '#day-mon').sort(by_order)
```

I find this version a little easier on the eyes if you don't use an anonymous function with `sort`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/N6AT7/1/